# Regex - How can I match a phrase to the end of a line?

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of phrases:

```
One: This is some data
Two: This is some more data
One: This is some more more data
Two: This is some more more more data
One: This is some more more more more data
```

I am trying to find a `regex` pattern which will match all the `"Two:"` lines (the entire line). 
I've been trying to get the correct pattern myself now for a good while with no luck, but I think this should be simple right?

I doubt it matters, but I'm using Python.

Thanks!

Comment: _ p l a c e h o l d e r _        `^Two:.*`

Comment: I have no idea why this was said to not be a real question. A novice question, sure, but since I'm learning regex, it's a totally legit question with totally legit answers. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a line that starts with the characters "Two" upto to the end, use this:

```
>>> re.match(r'^Two:.*$')
```

Comment: This did it: `^TWO:.*$\n`

Comment: @Brett So you wanted to match the new line or only the entire line? Update the questions with this new constraint

Comment: @Brett Maybe you should edit my answer and add the new-line to make it complete?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
>>> re.match(r'Two:.*$')
```

Comment: This almost does it, but it leaves the newline intact. Is there anyway to match the new line as well. I'm essentially trying to remove the entire line with a replace.

Comment: This did it: `^TWO:.*$\n`

Comment: I am afraid this regex does not match the start of a line. It can match a line that has "Two" in the middle and picks up everything upto the end. See my answer.

Comment: @Kata: `re.match` matches at the beginning of the line; your `^` is superfluous.

Comment: @Wooble I would rather be more explicit?

Comment: @Kata `match` is *explicitly* from the beginning of the line. Otherwise, use `search`.

Answer (score -1):

If this is python why don't you just use `if "Two:" in line:` to check if `"Two:"` is in that line. This is much easier than using regex.

Comment: OP wants it at the beginning on the line, but yes, `re` is overkill.

Comment: To each his own I guess.

Comment: you can use str.startswith('Two:')